# Can I connect a projector with HDMI to my Mac Pro's DVI connector using an adapter?

Tags: hdmi, projector, vga

I am interested in purchasing a projector that has native resolution of 1024x768. 
The projector has HDMI connector and VGA connector. I want to connect it to my Mac Pro computer which has only DVI connectors.

Can I simply connect a DVI cable to my Mac and then attach this cable to the projector with a DVI/HDMI adapter?

Will this maintain high quality video?

Answer (score 2):

You can get DVI to HDMI adapters from around $4 online on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002CZHN6), (just search for ‘DVI to HDMI’ on any online shopping site). As for the quality, most of the adapters that I have seen are able to do HD video and such. 
Hope this helped!

Comment: HDMI is basically just DVI with sound, so yes, those adapters are simple passthrough, its just a case of remapping where some pins go. No quality is lost at all, it should be completely transparent (just no sound).